# Fluid simulation on FBX file to three.js but animations are not showing! (How to make fluid simulation running on three.js)

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm new to Blender, and I'm struggling for days on this fluid simulation.

I have made a fluid simulation that goes well in blender, but it doesn't animated when I try to load the animation through FBX file using Three js.

I assume that my fluid simulation IS NOT SAVED because when I load my FBX file through the blender, all the fluid simulations I baked in the previous file is gone.

Here's my blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mfIkt0MNRpwBTxYjsX4pgXCAfIaZB7yR/view?usp=sharing

And Here's my javascript:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
import { FBXLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader';



let camera, scene, renderer

const clock = new THREE.Clock();

let mixer;



init();
animate();


function init() {

    const container = document.getElementById('canvas');
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 2, 2000);
    camera.position.set(0, 10, 30);
  

    scene = new THREE.Scene();


    // model 
    let loader = new FBXLoader();
    loader.load( '../static/assets/martini.fbx', function ( object ) {

        mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );
        
        let action = mixer.clipAction( object.animations[ 3 ] );
        action.play();



        object.traverse( function ( child ) {

            if ( child.isMesh ) {

                child.castShadow = true;
                child.receiveShadow = true;

            }

        } );
        object.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
        scene.add( object );

    } );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    
    controls.update();
}


//

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    const delta = clock.getDelta();

    if ( mixer ) {
        mixer.update( delta );
    }

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

    // stats.update();

}
```

And My current output is so static... I want to make a fluid animation running in Three js.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks for the link! I figured out that it is hard to export fluid simulations to three js...